# htaccess redirect from page with specific query string

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect, query-string

I'm new to the rewrite rules in htaccess and need some help with the following:

Page I want to redirect from:
http://example.com/webinar/?confirmed

Page I want to redirect to when a user tries to access the above URL:
http://example.com/webinar-thanks

What makes this tricky is that I will still need to access the original URL with different query strings such as:

- webinar/?stats
- webinar/?console

And so on.  I tried to do a 301 redirect but that redirects any attempt to access the /webinar page, regardless or the query string at the end, so I guess I need some rewrite syntax?

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^confirmed$
RewriteRule ^webinar/?$ /webinar-thanks [L,R]
```